# Ajax email form in MVC home page fails

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

On a web project I'm making in MVC, I have an Ajax email form inside my home page.  I want the form to prompt the user before sending the message, and then either do nothing or clear the form and inform the user of the message's successful delivery.  Instead, submitting the form always sends me to a "page" containing the fail message I send back and nothing else.

This is the form portion of the view.

```
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("SendEmailJson", new AjaxOptions
    {
        Confirm = "Send email?",
        OnSuccess = "MessageSent",
        OnFailure = "MessageSent"
    }))
    {
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Name")
            @Html.TextBox("FromName")
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Address")
            @Html.TextBox("FromEmail")
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Message")
            @Html.TextArea("Message", "", 5, 15, new { })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    }
```

This then calls the email function in the Home controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult SendEmailJson(EMailViewModel model)
    {
        string msg;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            bool suc = SendEmailMessage(model);
            msg = suc ? "Message sent" : "Error sending message. Please try again";
        }
        else
            msg = "An error occurred in the submission of this message.  Please try again.";
        return Json(msg);
    }

    private bool SendEmailMessage(EMailViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            var body = "Email from: {0} ({1})\n\nMessage:\n{2}";
            var msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("dummyMailAddress@address.net"));
            msg.From = new MailAddress(model.FromEmail);
            msg.Subject = "Contact from " + model.FromEmail + " through MyWebSiteName";
            msg.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
            using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
            {
                smtp.Send(msg);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The model is a very simple model:

```
public class EMailViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string FromName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string FromEmail { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Message")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I don't know why the program is failing on this, but I've kept a couple people waiting for some time and this is the last piece of the puzzle.  Please help.

EDIT: concerning SMTP settings, I have this in the Web.config file:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="dummyAddress@gmail.com">
        <network host="smtp.gmail.com"
                 port="587"
                 userName="dummyAddress@gmail.com"
                 password="dummyPW"
                 enableSsl="true" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

When I was figuring out how to send emails I put this same configuration data into a small test project and emails were sent without a problem.  However, in my main, true project these settings have no impact on the function always failing to send the message and also sending me to a new page with the message alone instead of giving me a popup showing the fail message.

Answer (score 0):

I found that you've missed some important settings inside `SendEmailMessage` method regarding `SmtpClient` initialization when sending email, here was some improvements:

```
private bool SendEmailMessage(EMailViewModel model)
{
    try
    {
        var body = "Email from: {0} ({1})\n\nMessage:\n{2}";
        var msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("dummyMailAddress@address.net"));
        msg.From = new MailAddress(model.FromEmail);
        msg.Subject = "Contact from " + model.FromEmail + " through MyWebSiteName";
        msg.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.Message);
        using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
        {
            //--- add these lines to define your e-mail provider
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            // set your SMTP server address here
            smtp.Host = "smtp.server.net"; 

            // use port number depending on your server SMTP port, e.g. 25, 465, 587, 2525
            smtp.Port = 587;

            // provide username & password for email access
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("serverusername", "serverpassword");

            // additionally, enable SSL if your email server supports secure connection
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            //--- end of added lines

            smtp.Send(msg);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

If you have pickup directory configuration on local server, change `SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network` to `SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis`.

Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: I had that stuff in the Web.config file.  All except for the delivery method.  I had another project with the same settings in the config file and emails were sent fine.